# Custom script for Current date in format Sat 20 Jul 2023 to display in div without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

**Note: not a duplicated because this is a custom made javascript without Jquery and no other answer answers this question**

I am trying not to depend on Jquery in my website, so I am creating this javascript to display the current date in format:

Sat 20 Jul 2023

It will display the date in the html div ID=first-date

Here is the Javascript code:

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var dayForText = today.getDay();
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var dia = today.getDay();
var display = days[dayForText] + " " + day + " " + months[month] + " " + year;
$('.first-date').html(display);
```

In HTML

```
<div id"first-date"></div>
```

The problem is that it is not displaying anything. Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing with this JavaScript code

```js
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var dayForText = today.getDay();
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var display = days[dayForText] + " " + day + " " + months[month] + " " + year;
document.getElementById("first-date").innerHTML = display;
```